# Automatically rebuild external cmake project after edit_cache

Tags: cmake

I have a main cmake project which has a PROJECT_INCLUDE_PATH which is a cached variable. I pass this variable as a CMAKE_ARGS parameter to an external project that I add using ExternalProject_Add().

The problem is, when I change the value of the PROJECT_INCLUDE_PATH using 'make edit_cache' the external project is not reconfigured.

Is there any way make the external project to be reconfigured and built automatically when the cached variable is changed in the main project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was not passing the correct variable. Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I always re-run CMake after modifying CMakeCache.txt (not that I do this often).  This would update the `ExternalProject_Add` call in your case.

Probably a safer option here is to avoid `make edit_cache`, and simply re-run CMake with a command line parameter of `-DPROJECT_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=<updated value>`.